# Javascript requires an extra refresh once data is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

When I submit a form with invalid two form data I need to click twice the submit button to display javascript alert. Then after inputting valid data I need to click twice to make not to display javascript alert

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dateinput').datepicker();
    $("#daterangeresult").click(function(){
        var start_date = "{{ form.data.start_date }}";
        var end_date = "{{ form.data.end_date }}";
        if (Date.parse(start_date) >= Date.parse(end_date)) {
            alert("Enter start date less than end date");
        }
    });
});
```

My html file is

```
<form action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
     Start Date: {{ form.start_date }}&nbsp;&nbsp; End Date:{{ form.end_date }}<br/>
     <input  type = "submit"  value = "See Results" id = "daterangeresult"></form>
```

what is problem here?

Comment: One `});` is missing.

Comment: @wared I just formatted the text. `})` was there, but it looks like no one sees it. See my edit here http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20757995/revisions

Comment: @Krasimir OP added the missing part after my own edit, sorry :)

Comment: `Date.parse('{{ form.data.start_date }}')`, weird...

Comment: include your HTML please